# Cannot call my method, what have I forgotten c# Skill:NOVICE

Tags: c#

Getting back into the swing of things after focusing on other assignments.

could someone tell me why I get an error for this.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("% unique numbers");

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int count = 0; count <= 5; count++)
        {

            DiceR();  // ------ Error here -----

        }

    }

    public void DiceR()
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, 6));

    }
}
```

Comment: The error message should tell you what you need to know - you can't call an instance (non-static) method from static one without having an instance of the object containing that method available.

Comment: You should post the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it `static`

```
static public void DiceR()
{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, 6));

}
```